# Changes are not reflected to database in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am struggling to make it work. This is just a plain code peace from (supposed) documentation and although it works with no error, nothing is changed in the database! I can't see a new class named V1! I am using 2.0.7 and Java 1.7

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:D:/orientdb/databases/GratefulDeadConcerts");
OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
try{
    OClass V = graph.getRawGraph().getMetadata().getSchema().getClass("V");
    OClass V1 = graph.getRawGraph().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass("V1", V);
    V1.createProperty("prop1", OType.STRING);
    V1.createProperty("prop2", OType.STRING);
    ODocument od = new ODocument(V1);
    od.field("prop1", "value1");
    od.field("prop2", "value2");
    od.save();

} catch( Exception e ) {
    System.out.println("ERROR:"+e.getMessage());
    graph.rollback();
}
finally {
    graph.shutdown();
    factory.close();
}
```

Comment: That piece of code works. How do you verify that there's no class named V1?

Comment: @vitorenesduarte Because I don't see it in Orientdb Studio